# can I stop parameters from being truncated?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I need to save an API key for a user so they can use my service.  I have the persistance and retrieval all figured out and I can cut and paste the key from in my browser which I expect users will do.  Not ideal, but it is a one time thing.  The problem I'm having is the parameter being passed in the response json, is a truncated value.  Here is an example.

```js
{
"responseId": "169a5307-2148-4d3d-bdd8-a50a1c365aaf",
"queryResult": {
    "queryText": "set my key to 16FF43FE-A8D9-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "parameters": {
        "APIKey": "16FF43FE-A8D9"
```

Any recommendations here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogflow isn't meant to easily parse identifiers and keys, so you may see an issue like this one.

In good voice UI design you would not want to enter API keys manually, but one workaround would be to get the full key from Dialogflow's raw query text rather than trying to extract it as a parameter.

Comment: Yeah, not ideal for sure, but I need to talk to an API on the requestors behalf for fulfillment.  I was hoping the might be a cleaner way then getting parsing the raw query text, but this is easy enough.  Thanks @Nick

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing my solution for anyone else looking to do something similar.  It is an edge case, even for my assistant, but a necessary one.

```js
  function setKey(agent) {
    var myRegexp = /my (?:key|API key) is (.*)/gi;
    var queryText = request.body.queryResult.queryText;
    var match = myRegexp.exec(queryText);
    conv.user.storage.apiKey = match[1];
    conv.ask('Ok, saving ' + match[1]);
    agent.add(conv);
  }
```